# How to make custom audio format and custom player

Tags: audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

Like .mp3, .wav can i able to create my own custom format?. Which can be played only by the custom player i created. But has same quality as .mp3
I don't want my songs copied by others. Those who have my player can play it.
Is there any opensource software's available?

Comment: it will eventually be reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but it will be very difficult. You will need to come up with a proprietary audio encoding/compression format, which is still not perfected even by those doing it for decades.

What you should do instead is this. Encrypt an audio file such as an MP3 with your favourite encryption algorithm, and a password only you know. Then in your "custom player", simply decrypt the file before playing it. This way you can encrypt MySong.mp3 to MySong.whatever which is encrypted and unplayable unless you know the password that is embedded into your player.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt Olan. This is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a "config.yaml" file with wave data (e.g: "
metadata:
sounds:
- 0
- 1
- 0"),
then use python's numpy, to create a numpy-array, then make a sine wave out of this, then drop the sine wave into a sine-wave-to-audio converter (you can code it yourself) and evoilà, you have your audio. Now you need a decoder (you can, again, code it yourself). I tried this by myself, it wasn't easy, tho i learned something.

Description:

y+ = wave high, y- = wave low, x+ = time flow